# Windows Scripting - Editing Text File

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file, cmd

***C:\Incoming\records.txt***

```
11 record(s) received

5021462426325

5021462426325

5021462426325

5021462426325

5021462426325

8901090213511

8901090213511

8901090213511

8901090213511

0080432400708

0080432400708
```

The desired format of the file contents

```
5021462426325,5021462426325,5021462426325,5021462426325,5021462426325,8901090213511,8901090213511,8901090213511,8901090213511,0080432400708,0080432400708
```

Then copy this from `C:\Incoming` to `C:\Outgoing` and place the old file in `C:\Stored`.

Comment: I'd learn Powershell or install Windows ports of some standard UNIX/Linux tools for scripting.

Comment: That is precisely the constraint, else I could have easily done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=* skip=1" %%i in (C:\Incoming\records.txt) do echo|set /p="%%i,">>C:\Outgoing\records.txt
move C:\Incoming\records.txt C:\Stored\records.txt
```

Comment: There is a preceding comma and Can I just do a wildcard with the file name? --- The output is ,5021462426325,5021462426325,5021462426325,5021462426325,5021462426325,8901090213511,8901090213511,8901090213511,8901090213511,

Comment: No, you can't use a wildcard. I just copied your text and there is no proceeding comma, have you edited the command? There is a comma at the end actually, but not at the start.

Comment: Okie, I think I understand what the issue might be. There is a newline between the first record and the line "11 record(s) received". How do i handle that?

Comment: @shoonya - Change `skip=1` to `skip=2`.